# How to get the values of the css style attributes in gwt

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

Is it possible to get the width of a border for a panel, and/or other css style attributes values from a class? (if the css style attributes has been declared using ui:style from uibinder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do with the [com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?overview-summary.html). UIObject (so as the Widget) has the `getElement()` method which returns DOM Element.

Try getElement() -> getStyle() -> getBorderWidth(). In the Style class there are appropriate methods for many CSS properties. For the other props Style has `getProperty(String)` method (to get "backgroungPosition" for example). This should work for ui:style as well.